# AWS Lambda deployment through CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Simple question: I wrote a lambda function (Golang) which I usually deploy manually, through either the AWS CLI or the console.

Recently I moved the code repository to CodeCommit and I'm thinking about using the other dev services, too.

I guess I should write a `buildspec.yml` for CodeBuild to create the build zip on my behalf and upload it to S3.

What I can find enough (and clear) documentation about is CodeDeploy.

The deployment action is extremely simple, as I understand it, deploy to Lambda a zip stored in my S3 bucket. Though, the only official documentation I found revolves around Cloudformation, SAM, etc.

I'd prefer to keep my CI/CD as simple as possible. What do you suggest? Do I get it wrong? Can you please point me out in the right direction?